# ISO-8859-1 character set in WCF Request

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, iso-8859-1

I have written a REST WCF service that is called by an external API. The request is sending the XML POST request in ISO-8859-1. This results in a 400 bad request response from my service.

Here's a stub of my service method:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method ="POST", UriTemplate="/", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
 [FaultContract(typeof(String))]
 XmlElement GetInstructions(XmlElement request);
```

Currently, I'm trying to intercept the request and return the appropriate content type:

```
public class XmlContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        return WebContentFormat.Xml;
    }
}
```

This only works if I remove the charset=ISO-8859-1 from the headers.

I've seen examples of using IClientMessageInspector and IDispatchMessageInspector, but those seem specific to SOAP, unless I'm missing something.

What can I do to fix this?  I don't have any control over the incoming request.

Thanks for any insight.

Here's the first part of the XML request:

```
POST http://localhost:54814/autocallerid.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54814
Content-Type: text/xml, charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1734

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:context:schema:os">
    <Subject SubjectCategory="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
 ....
```

Comment: What does the start of the XML declaration look like?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  I resolved the issue.

I just needed to change the input type from an XmlElement to a Stream and return the format as WebContentFormat.Raw.

Like so:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method ="POST", UriTemplate = "/info", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
 [FaultContract(typeof(String))]
 XmlElement GetInstructions(Stream request);
```

And this:

```
public class XmlContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        return WebContentFormat.Raw;
    }
}
```